# Quickest method to get requests on all pages with loops

Tags: python, loops, request

I'm working out a method on getting a request, and converting to json all the pages from a given url. I'm parsing in a dictionary for different search query's for the website, however each query has a different number of pages. My initial attempt was to create a long `if-else` statements, after grabbing the total number of pages.

So something like:

```
for key, value, page in zip(pages_c['keys'], pages_c['values'],pages_c['pages']):
    if key == "clothing/womens-clothing/dresses" and value == '20s':
        for i in range(1, page):
            ...
    elif key == "clothing/womens-clothing/dresses" and value == '30s':
        for i in range(1, page):        
            ...
...
...
...
```

Where `pages_c` is given as:

```
pages_c = {'keys':['clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/dresses','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats','clothing/womens-clothing/jackets-and-coats'],
          'values':['20s','30s','40s','50s','60s','70s','80s','90s','20s','30s','40s','50s','60s','70s','80s','90s'],
          'pages':[159,169,250,250,250,250,250,250,26,33,86,161,250,250,250,250]}
```

However, this approach would take an awfully long time! and I want to know what's the quickest method in doing this. My expectation is to fill requests, so using the code above, likeso:

```
pall_pages = defaultdict(list)
for key, value, page in zip(pages_c['keys'], pages_c['values'],pages_c['pages']):
    if key == "clothing/womens-clothing/dresses" and value == '20s':
        for pag_num in range(1,page):
            data = {
          'log_performance_metrics': 'true',
          'specs[async_search_results][]': 'Search2_ApiSpecs_WebSearch',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][detected_locale][language]': 'en-GB',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][detected_locale][currency_code]': 'GBP',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][detected_locale][region]': 'GB',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][locale][language]': 'en-GB',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][locale][currency_code]': 'GBP',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][locale][region]': 'GB',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][query]': 'q',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][query_type]': 'qt',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][results_per_page]': 'result_count',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][min_price]': 'min',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][max_price]': 'max',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][q]': val,
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][explicit]': '1',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][ship_to]': 'GB',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][page]': str(pag_num),
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][ref]': 'pagination',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][facet]': keys,
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][referrer]': f'https://www.etsy.com/search/{keys}/dresses?q={val}&explicit=1&locationQuery=2635167&ship_to=GB&page={pag_num}&ref=pagination',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][user_id]': '',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][request_type]': 'pagination_preact',
          'specs[async_search_results][1][is_eligible_for_spa_reformulations]': 'false',
          'view_data_event_name': 'search_async_pagination_specview_rendered'
        }
            r = requests.post('https://www.etsy.com/api/v3/ajax/bespoke/member/neu/specs/async_search_results', headers=headers, data=data)
            print(r)
```

Comment: i think it's the `requests.post` that takes time.

Comment: have you the same lines of codes in the for pag_num for each  if key== and value == ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have same lines of code for each if-else, you just could write:

```
for key, value, page in zip(pages_c['keys'], pages_c['values'],pages_c['pages']):
    for pag_num in range(1,page):
        data = {
      'log_performance_metrics': 'true',
      'specs[async_search_results][]': 'Search2_ApiSpecs_WebSearch',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][detected_locale][language]': 'en-GB',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][detected_locale][currency_code]': 'GBP',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][detected_locale][region]': 'GB',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][locale][language]': 'en-GB',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][locale][currency_code]': 'GBP',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][locale][region]': 'GB',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][query]': 'q',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][query_type]': 'qt',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][results_per_page]': 'result_count',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][min_price]': 'min',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][name_map][max_price]': 'max',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][q]': val,
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][explicit]': '1',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][ship_to]': 'GB',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][page]': str(pag_num),
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][ref]': 'pagination',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][facet]': keys,
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][parameters][referrer]': f'https://www.etsy.com/search/{keys}/dresses?q={val}&explicit=1&locationQuery=2635167&ship_to=GB&page={pag_num}&ref=pagination',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][search_request_params][user_id]': '',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][request_type]': 'pagination_preact',
      'specs[async_search_results][1][is_eligible_for_spa_reformulations]': 'false',
      'view_data_event_name': 'search_async_pagination_specview_rendered'
    }

        r = requests.post('https://www.etsy.com/api/v3/ajax/bespoke/member/neu/specs/async_search_results', headers=headers, data=data)
        print(r)
```

Comment: I can implement the post quickly with `scrapy` however, I just wanted a quick method to do what I mentioned above. Otherwise, I'll have to implement the `if-else` statement. The use of request is just for example.

Comment: ok i misunderstand your question..you want to simplify all if else...